# I dont know how to interact with my wallet to request verification on OpenSea

Tags: gnosis-safe, opensea

My company launched an NFT - proceeds are in the Gnosis Safe. Recently our development partner transferred the "smart contract" to my wallet. Now I dont see it or know how to interact with it, need to take action to get verified on Open Sea. Our collections meets all OpenSea verification criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the partner transferred the ownership of the smart contract to you. If so, it will not appear in the wallet. You have to visit the Contract page on the Block Explorer and connect your wallet to interact with it.